# Reading Arduino int array with Processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I have an arduino-processing communication problem.
I have arduino code that gives me X-and/Y coordinates from a touchScreen
and it works well, no problem with that, I got my X- and Y coordinates.
BUT I need to visualize that, I am trying to write code in Processing 3.0, so that I will be able to see on my computer, where the touchFolie was being touched.
So I need to send the x-y from arduino to processing so that I will be able to draw. 
Does anyone know how can I send an integer array[X,Y] from arduino to processing ??

Comment: This may help you. [Serial \ Libraries \ Processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/)

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to have a play with the [Serial library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/) in Processing and the **SerialRead** example (in *Processing > File > Examples > Libraries > serial > SimpleRead*)

Let's say you're starting from scratch.
To send data from Arduino you need to open a [Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) connection.
At this stage the only important details is the baud rate: how fast is the data flowing.

Here's a minimal Arduino data out example:

```
void setup() {
  //initialize the Serial library with baud rate 115200
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  //write data to the serial port
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(1000);
}
```

If you open Serial Monitor in the Arduino software and set the baud rate to 115200 you should see **test** printed once a second.

To read the same data in Processing, aside from specifying the baud rate, you must also specify the serial port (what you have selected in Tools > Port and is also listed at the bottom right of your current Arduino sketch):

```
import processing.serial.*; 

void setup() { 
  //update the serial port index based on your setup
  println(Serial.list());
  Serial arduino = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 115200); 
  arduino.bufferUntil('\n'); 
} 

void draw() { 
} 

void serialEvent(Serial p) { 
  //read the string from serial
  String rawString = p.readString();
  println(rawString);
}
```

Notice that we tell Processing to buffer until it reaches a `'\n'` character so we don't have to worry about waiting for every single character and append it manually to a String. Instead using [bufferUntil()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html), [serialEvent()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/serialEvent_.html) and [readString()](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readString_.html) most of the work is done for us.

Now that you can send a String from Arduino and read it in Processing, you can do some String manipulation, like splitting a string into multiple using a separator via the [split()](https://processing.org/reference/split_.html) function:

```
String xyValues = "12,13";
printArray(xyValues.split(","));
```

The last part would be converting the split values from `String` to `int`:

```
String xyValues = "12,13";
String[] xy = xyValues.split(","); 
printArray(xy);
int x = int(xy[0]);
int y = int(xy[1]);
println("integer values: " + x + " , " + y);
```

So, in theory, you should be able to do something like this on Arduino:

```
int x,y;

void setup() {
  //initialize serial 
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  //simulating the x,y values from the touch screen, 
  //be sure to replace with the actual readings from 
  //NOTE! If the screen returns values above 255, scale them to be from 0 to 255
  x = map(analogRead(A0),0,1024,0,255);
  y = map(analogRead(A1),0,1024,0,255);
  //write the data to serial
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(y);
  Serial.print("\n");
}
```

then on the Arduino side:

```
import processing.serial.*; 

float x,y;

void setup() { 
  size(400,400);
  //update the serial port index based on your setup
  Serial arduino = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 115200); 
  arduino.bufferUntil('\n'); 
} 

void draw() { 
  background(0); 
  ellipse(x,y,10,10);
} 

void serialEvent(Serial p) { 
  //read the string from serial
  String rawString = p.readString();
  //trim any unwanted empty spaces
  rawString = rawString.trim();
  try{
    //split the string into an array of 2 value (e.g. "0,127" will become ["0","127"]
    String[] values = rawString.split(",");
    //convert strings to int
    int serialX = int(values[0]);
    int serialY = int(values[1]);
    //map serial values to sketch coordinates if needed
    x = map(serialX,0,255,0,width);
    y = map(serialY,0,255,0,height);
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("Error parsing string from Serial:");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**Note** The Arduino code above will probably not solve your problem as it is, you need to integrate your touch sensor code, but hopefully it provides some hints on how you can tackle this.

Sending a String, then parsing it is one approach, but not the most efficient. If you have your x,y values in a 0-255 range, you could send just 2 bytes (each coordinate as a single `char`) instead of up to 8 bytes, but for now it may be much easier to play with Strings rather than jump into bytes straight away.

Comment: hey George, well this makes sence what you wrote, and its surely logic, BUT i tried the Code on the Arduino-Side :   int x,y;  void setup() {
  //initialize serial 
  Serial.begin(115200);
}void loop() {
  //simulating the x,y values from the touch screen, 
  //be sure to replace with the actual readings from 
  //NOTE! If the screen returns values above 255, scale them to be from 0 to 255
  x = map(analogRead(A0),0,1024,0,255);
  y = map(analogRead(A1),0,1024,0,255);
  //write the data to serial
  Serial.write(x+","+y+"\n");
}

Comment: and im getting this error : invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'   // can i ask what are those  "+" signs in Serial write ? what do they do ..

Comment: My bad, I've updated that part of the code. It's basically complaining that it can not merge a constant array of characters with another character. I've split the statement onto multiple lines (which makes it easier to understand). The + were my attempt to concatenate, but I forgot that you can't simply concatenate different types in Arduino(c++) as you do in Processing(java)

Comment: hey again , well the arduino code is working , i just tried your code , i will integrate my touch sensor code , no prob, BUT the processing code is not working proprely, i mean this processing code must make the ellipse moving dempending on X and Y, which it istnt doing , ellipse does not move, and its showing this error :java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at sketch_150923a.serialEvent(sketch_150923a.java:45)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at

Comment: i think its better to just paste my arduino code hier , perhaps you could find a way to do that.  Arduino code for my touchscreen:  

#include <stdint.h>
#include "TouchScreen.h"

#define YP A2  
#define XM A3  
#define YM 8   
#define XP 9   

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300);
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(void) {
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint();
  
  if (p.z > ts.pressureThreshhold) {
     Serial.print("X = "); Serial.print(p.x);
     Serial.print("\tY = "); Serial.print(p.y);
     Serial.print("\tPressure = "); Serial.println(p.z);
  }
  delay(100);
}

Comment: this arduino code i have, is a example from a library, so its working find, it shows me x,y and the pressure, but i need to visualize that in processing , so when i touch the screen i want to get a point, when i run the processing , with the x and y coordinates from arduino , i dont care about the pressure ,, so what do you think George?

Comment: I've have a look through the code, but in the meantime have a look at the updated Arduino code above. I was using ```Serial.write```(wrote x,y as bytes) in Arduino where I was supposed to use ```Serial.print```(writes x,y as string)

Comment: NOW its working with Serial.print  this is a already good,    i will try now to geht my code integrated

Comment: Something like this should work: ```#include <stdint.h> 
#include "TouchScreen.h" 
#define YP A2 
#define XM A3 
#define YM 8 
#define XP 9 

TouchScreen ts = TouchScreen(XP, YP, XM, YM, 300); 

void setup(void) { 
  Serial.begin(115200); 
} 

void loop(void) { 
  TSPoint p = ts.getPoint(); 
  if (p.z > ts.pressureThreshhold) { 
    Serial.print(p.x); 
    Serial.print(","); 
    Serial.print(p.y); 
    Serial.print("\n");
   } 
   delay(100); 
}``` but I can't test without the touch screen. You seem to get the idea though :) Good luck!

Comment: i have added println(x); and println(y); in the processing code in void draw() , to see if im getting the x and y , when i run the wohle thing , im getting numbres printed in processing ,from 0 to 9900 ,and the ellipse disappears , could we have missed somth. on the arduino side like map for (p.x) and (p.y) ? p.x and p.y give on arduino x and y smth. from 100 to 970

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to vote/mark the answer if it was helpful ;)

Comment: Also, if you have a 32u4 based Arduino (like Leonardo/Yun/Zero/Due) you can use the [Mouse class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) which allows your arduino to act as a usb mouse (simplifying Processing code). On the Uno you'd need something like [V-USB](http://www.practicalarduino.com/projects/virtual-usb-keyboard) or [LUFA](http://smartinteractionlab.com/lufa-example-turning-your-arduino-into-a-keyboard/), but that's a more advanced approach so you'd need to be more comfortable with Arduino before trying that.

Answer (score -2):

This [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing) will help you. 
5 minutes and you are able to connect each others!

### EDIT:

First of all look the first part of the tutorial ("From Arduino..." "...To processing"). 
In arduino you have just to send your coordinates in your Serial.

```
Serial.println(coordX);
Serial.println(coordY);
```

In processing you receive this coordinates as Text but you are able to convert it in Float with `parseFloat()` function.

This is the code you need in Processing to receive your coordinates and store them in variables.

```
    import processing.serial.*;
    Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
    String val;     // Data received from the serial port

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    boolean first = true;
    setup() {
       String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
       myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 
    }
    void draw() {
      if ( myPort.available() > 0) {  // If data is available,
         val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         // read it and store it in val
         if (first) {
            x = parseFloat(val);
            first = false;
            println("x= "+val); //print it out in the console
            } 
         else {
             y = parseFloat(val);
             first = true;
             println("y= "+val); //print it out in the console
             }
      }
```

I hope this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: hey Peto , well i did got that , BUT i need to get the Values of two integers X-Y, in the tutorial its about a Text, it must modifaicated for integer Reading

Comment: I modify my answer, improving it.

Comment: i am getting an error in the processing , well it starts working fine and couple seconds later it stops and shows me this error on line 21: null pointer exception ,, i haveno idea what that is

Comment: I forgot the setup() method in the answer, sorry. Edited. Let me know if the problem persists.